# Moving A JLabel Within A JPanels Limit (Think Its A Math Problem) JAVA

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jlabel

Also this might help others wanting to move JLabels around too.

So here is the situation:

1. 1 JPanel with an item in it.
2. 1 JLabel with an Img in it as the ICON.
3. I want to move the JLabel around the panel but not out of the bounds of the panel (So the user can see ALL of the image on the screen)

Here is the code:
I initialize there:

```
int randH = 0;
int randW = 0;
int targetHeight = 0;
int targetWidth = 0;
```

Then when the panel opens depending on which (target / IMG) is loaded:

```
    targetHeight = jLabel1.getHeight();
    targetWidth = jLabel1.getWidth();
```

Then when the label is clicked I called this code to move it around:

```
                int posH = jPanel1.getHeight() - targetHeight;
                int posW = jPanel1.getWidth() - targetWidth;

                randH = new Random().nextInt(posH) - jLabel1.getHeight();
                randW = new Random().nextInt(posW) - jLabel1.getWidth();

                if (randH <= 0) {

                    int num = (int) (Math.random() * 5);;
                    randH = num;
                }

                if (randW <= 0) {

                    int num = (int) (Math.random() * 5);;
                    randW = num;
                }
                if (randH >= posH) {

                    int num = (int) (Math.random() * 5);;
                    randH = posH - num;
                }

                if (randW >= posW) {

                    int num = (int) (Math.random() * 5);;
                    randW = posW - num;
                }
                jPanel1.setLayout(null);
                jLabel1.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(200, 300), jLabel1.getPreferredSize()));
                jLabel1.setLocation(randW, randH);

                jLabel1.setVisible(true);
```

so sometimes the IMG is partially out of the panel when the value is greater than the dimension of the JPanel

Any reason for this?

Comment: *Think Its A Math Problem*  - do some debugging and display the intermediate values of your calculations. Then when you get a value that is not expected you fix the problem.

Comment: I tried that and its good 99.9% of the time. and when I found its not I'm not checking the values :D ie, I check seems good then I stop checking and its off

Comment: Well you have "random" logic in your code. So you need to determine why your random logic is generating values that are too large. I don't understand why you have two sets of random logic. If you have a panel with a width of 100 and an image with a width of 20, then the location of the label can be 0 - 80. So you generate a number in that range.

Comment: so basically the way it paints the JLabels is from the top left corner so i get the height and width and then need to take off the size of the IMG so that the whole image is in the panels view. if I don't do that is will put the IMG out of view

Comment: something like this ? int randomNum = new Random().nextInt((posH - 0) + 1) + 0;

Comment: Not understanding your logic. Why would you subtract 0 from a number? Why would you add 1 to then number? Why would you add 0 to the number?

Comment: Generally, the way you solve this JLabel moving "problem" is to draw the image directly on a drawing JPanel.  The Oracle tutorial [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) will show you how.

Comment: *the way you solve this JLabel moving "problem"* - whether you use a JLabel or paint the image you still have a problem if you don't get the x/y location correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after checking it all and thanks to everyone for the help!

```
randH = new Random().nextInt((posH - 0) + 1) + 0;
```

seems to have gotten me to where I need to be

```
posH = is the max value
0 = is the min value 
+1 = include max
+0 = include min
```

and to explain a little more, the following code is to make sure the IMG isn't hugging the panel border so there are at least 5 pixels between the image and border.

```
                if (randH <= 0) {

                    int num = (int) (Math.random() * 5);;
                    randH = num;
                }

                if (randW <= 0) {

                    int num = (int) (Math.random() * 5);;
                    randW = num;
                }
                if (randH >= posH) {

                    int num = (int) (Math.random() * 5);;
                    randH = posH - num;
                }

                if (randW >= posW) {

                    int num = (int) (Math.random() * 5);;
                    randW = posW - num;
                }
```

this is to the best of my knowledge, maybe didn't do it well :D